# Tray icon to be visible even in inactive state

Tags: system-tray

My system tray icon going hidden from try when it is not active. I want to program the notifier icon to be always available visible even in inactive state.

Comment: What language are we talking about?  C#, MFC, Visual C++, java, etc.

Comment: is it a winform app? and which language you coding in? more information please